# Can't get MSI minor upgrade to work

Tags: windows, windows-installer, upgrade

When I try and apply a minor upgrade to my application, I launch the installer and (depending upon the combination of settings I try) I get either a:

- repair/remove dialog
- prompt for the install directory

I don't believe I should get either of these prompts.  I'm mostly expecting the installer to automatically apply the upgrade and not prompt for anything.  I think I'm doing everything correctly in the Visual Studio setup project:

- upgraded the version from 1.0.0 to 1.1.0
- left the product code the same
- updated the package code
- left the upgrade code the same
- launch the installer with the parameters REINSTALLMODE=vomus REINSTALL=ALL

I've tried just about every combination of codes/flags and techniques, but cannot seem to get the update applied.

Any ideas of what else I can try?

Comment: Additional details: I edited the product code and it started working.  When prompted with the repair/remove option, I picked repair and the upgrade was applied.  Is there anyway to get rid of this dialog?  If I'm running the installer with the REINSTALLMODE/REINSTALL flags, shouldn't that be automatic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get it to work I:

- upgraded the version from 1.0.0 to 1.1.0
- left the product code the same (said No when prompted by Visual Studio)
- updated the package code (Visual Studio did this automatically)
- did not change the upgrade code
- launch the installer with the parameters REINSTALLMODE=vomus REINSTALL=ALL

Just as I had indicated in my question, and it seems to be working.  I can successfully apply an upgrade.  However, when I run the installer I am still prompted with a repair/remove option.  But, that's a different question I guess.

Answer (score 0):

**Just first things first**: *Are you sure you haven't **re-used the package GUID in both MSI files**, or at some point during deployment work and testing?*

Try rebuilding both MSI files with new GUIDs to "de-couple" them from any existing cached versions and then try test installing again. Change both the package code and product code. Better yet: test these new versions on a clean virtual machine to ensure a proper test environment unaffected by past sins. Your developer system could have gremlins in its Windows installer database due to package guid clashes. If this is the case package installation becomes total XFiles - the strangest things can happen.

---

**More details**:
If the package GUID is the same for two MSI files, Windows Installer will treat them as the same file by definition - no matter what they contain. This can cause all kinds of strange problems that are hard to clean up and debug. Note that this can happen even if you just forgot to update it once since installation of an MSI will cause it to be cached on the system in the C:\Windows\Installer folder (this folder is hidden and protected). This cached copy will be re-used if an MSI file with the same GUID is launched (at least this was the case for earlier versions of Windows Installer - there could be fixes for this now).

If you are using Installshield you should enable the "always generate packaging GUID" feature to ensure this never happens. Package GUID should always change for every single build - there is no reason whatsoever to keep it hard coded. I believe WIX takes care of generating the package GUID automagically, unless you specifically override it.

Comment: Thanks...but yes, I double checked and Visual Studio automatically changed the package code.